# IOS Swift Tab Application set back to First View when clicked Tab Icon

Tags: ios, swift, webview, tabs

In IOS Swift, I made a Tab Application has a `UITableView` and link to a `WebView`, I clicked on the TableView then the `WebView` showed. I clicked  Second Tab and clicked back to First Tab.

Questions

1) The First tab is keeping to show the `WebView`, how to force back to show the TableView.

2) The Content in `WebView` will align to Center Vertically (leave a Blank top) , not align on top as initial, I need click back and re-click the table cell to launch the `WebView` again, it became normal.

Comment: there is two tabs 1) webview 2) tableview right?

Comment: if it is so then select 2nd tab programmatically `[tabBar setSelectedItem: [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]];`

Comment: A tab application, has two tabs, each tab has a tableview and webview, after clicked table cell, launch a web view.

Tab1--> TableVew1 --> WebView1.
Tab2-->TableView2 --> WebView2

Comment: While the WebView1 showed, I click the Tab2 and then Tab1, I suppose to show the first vIew of Tab1, i.e. TableView1, but It is keeping on WebView1.